# Доступ к статичным изображениям и css файлам в java сервлетах

Tags: java, css, intellij-idea, servlet

Простенький сервлет генерирует в doGet html контент с помощью freemarket-а. Проблемы возникли когда в шаблон добавил ссылку на css-файл и изображения - Томкат их не находит, хотя они есть в папке приложения - см. организацию проекта в идее - соотвественно в браузере изображения не отображаются и стили игнорируются. 
Не подскажите как нужно все организовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: как просили пом-файл:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.local.app</groupId>
<artifactId>jira-scr</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>jira-scr Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
        <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.23</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <compilerArgument>-parameters</compilerArgument>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

facets:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

artefacts:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

settings:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: покажите как вы деплоите на сервер, покажите pom, покажите facets и artefacts

Comment: деплой идет через саму идею - "facets и artefacts" - у меня вроде не JSP/JSF приложение. Просто все это в новинку ибо только учу сервлеты под java.

Comment: В любом случае вы должны деплоить артефакт. Покажите настройки конфигурации деплоя

Comment: все понял... добавил...

Comment: Установите галочку include the project build. Также покажите настройки конфигурации деплоя (справа сверху, когда нажимаете run)

Comment: добавил скрин settings-ов...

Comment: вы не поставили галочку Deploy applications conf in tomcat instance

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52436/discussion-between-dreadangel-and-senior-automator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблемы были в web.xml и в настройках деплоя. 
 
В web.xml необходимо было добавить все необходмые компоненты.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```